# java:10: error: cannot find symbol (with jEdit)

Tags: java, object, jedit

I've code on Java since three months. I started with Intellij Idea, but it's so heavy for my computers, so I've decided code using jEdit.

But many software that I've programmed it's in the way of Intellij, so I oppened my programs on jEdit.

As usual like me, I create a principal class that calls to next class into an Object like the next way:

```
W1 ejectuar = new W1 ;
```

But on jEdti prints the next error:

```
INDT.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        W1 ejecutar = new W1() ;
        ^
  symbol:   class W1
  location: class INDT
INDT.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        W1 ejecutar = new W1() ;
                          ^
  symbol:   class W1
  location: class INDT
2 errors
```

Intellij create the class into a package, but I don't know how to link the both class to compile.

Comment: jEdit itself is only a text editor and cannot compile sources at all. You should mention which plugin you talk about and how you set up your stuff and where your files are lying, then, maybe someone can help you.

Comment: @Vampire I use the Terminal to compile. I've ensured to have saved the two class un the same folder.

Comment: If you use the terminal to compile and not some jEdit plugin, I don't understand how you think jEdit is involved and why you say that jEdit prints an error. If both classes are in the same folder, please add your command you are executing when you get that output and maybe also the contents of those two classes.

Comment: I Downloaded the command Plugin. And I use javac classname.java then java classname

Answer (score 1):

Call `javac -cp . classname.java` instead of `javac classname.java` and it should work.